# How can I create a texture that looks like a woven strands of metal?

Tags: mesh

I need your help and advise, I'd like to create a mesh like the below shown image , shall I duplicate a several torus and mix them ?! or create curve and mix them, really I don't have the correct .

[image: ring]

Comment: You could try a *Wireframe* modifier on a torus but it will be hard to smooth things out. Maybe try with Bezier curve objects if you don't mind the self intersections.

Comment: The skin modifier gives similar results to the wireframe but I find it gives a cleaner mesh, though it can be slower before being applied. You don't need to merge multiple torus to get the result, just add  and move edge loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try doing this with a procedural texture on a torus.

Using a simple voronoi texture and scaling it so that it creates a texture for the vertical strands. And feeding that to control the mix between a transparent and glossy shader.

[image]

Then use the same kind of setup but rotated 90 degrees for the horizontal strands.

[image]

Then mix the two textures (with a multiply operation), and use the resulting image to control the mix between glossy and transparent, but also use that to create some displacement. Adding a Brightness/Contrast node will give you control for the transparency and the amount of displacement.

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.]

Comment: how did you create  the vertical and horizontal lines ? as the texture for the color only !!

Comment: I'd like to thanks "cegaton" for teach me how to make a texture that looks like a woven strands of metal, 

as I'm wandering if he can or some one can tell me how to model the above  images

Comment: The mesh is a simple torus. Press Shift+A then choose Add>Mesh>Torus

Comment: for me the torus is solid not lines like you, please check it --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/s43he.jpg

Comment: Did you UV unwrap the mesh?

Comment: no, I didn't ...

Comment: Oh, thanks it's working, but is there away to build it as mesh instead of texture, so I can print it, as the printer will recognize the mesh only

Comment: @AbdulrazaqAl-Essa - You should edit your question and add the fact that this is for 3D printing so you will get more specific answers.